# Efficient find of first element of a vector that meets a logical condition in Matlab

Tags: matlab, performance, find, vectorization

I need to find the index of the first element of a vector A that satisfies the condition A(i) <= b. I know before hand that at least one element of A meets the condition. I tried this, but it is very inefficient:

```
i = find(A <= b, 1)
```

It seems that Matlab is doing the equivalent of this:

```
X = A <= b
find(X, 1)
```

There is waste in calculating all elements of X: you should stop as soon as you encounter an i such that A(i) <= b. So I tried this:

```
for i = 1 : length(A)

    if A(i) <= b

        break

    end

end
```

But the iterative code is even slower than the vectorized code.

Is there any way to perform this find more efficiently?

Comment: I think the only way you're going to get faster than creating the entire logical vector `X` is to write the function in C. Unless you've identified this as a bottleneck in your program, I'd leave it as it is.

Comment: Are your entries random? Basically, can `i` be 1 and also `numel(A)`? Usually you can speed things up if you make additional assumptions, e.g. search only in a particular region of A, etc..

Comment: Heuristics may help alot, depending on the data. Test only the first n entries and only revert to checking all if the solution is not in these. Or else you could try combining the loop approach and the find approach by examining the data block-wise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you came to the conclusion that the looping code is slower than the vectorised code, but here is a benchmark and some context for the results!

I am using 2015b, so this will likely take advantage of Matlab's [new(ish) JIT compiler](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/02/12/run-code-faster-with-the-new-matlab-execution-engine/).

---

```
function benchie()
    A = rand(1e9, 1);
    b = 0.01;
    f = @() original(A,b);
    g = @() usingloop(A,b);
    disp(['Original with logical A <= b:    ', num2str(timeit(f)), ' sec']);
    disp(['Looping until found, then break: ', num2str(timeit(g)), ' sec']);
end
% Both of these functions return the same value for idx
function idx = original(A,b)
    idx = find(A <= b, 1);
end    
function idx = usingloop(A,b)
    for idx = 1:length(A)
        if A(idx) <= b
            break
        end
    end
end
```

**Output**:

```
Original with logical A <= b:    0.83666 sec

Warning: The measured time for F [function g] may be inaccurate because it is running
too fast. Try measuring something that takes longer. 
> In timeit (line 158)
  In benchie (line 7) 
Looping until found, then break: 1.8043e-06 sec
```

**Summary**:

Making `A` as big as my RAM would allow (8GB), the `usingloop` method is still too quick for `timeit` to deem itself accurate! Both of these functions give the same answer, and I think `usingloop` is orders of magnitude quicker.

I would love to include a plot showing time comparisons for different size arrays, but can't as `usingloop` is too quick...

---

**Note:** I am using `idx` as my variable instead of `i`. This is because `i` is the complex constant `sqrt(-1)` by default, and in over-writing that you are going to incur a (small) performance hit straight away!

---

**Edit:**

I ran another test, with `A = 1e8:-1:1;` and `b` at values every tenth of the way through `A` to see when the overhead of the vectorisation is outweighed by the time needed to loop further into the array. Below is the output:

[image: benchmark]

You can see that the overhead for logical comparison is almost all of the time required, and the actual indexing of that vector is very small irrespective of location. In contrast, the looping method is terrible once the desired element is a short way into the array.

Given MATLAB's reputation for rapid computations using vectorisation and logical indexing, I will echo @beaker's comment by saying that a custom (compiled) C function may be the only way to see any improvement over your original method.

Comment: If I may make a couple of suggestions, first, using random values you don't really know if the first value stopped the loop, or the last. It might be more instructive to have the first `A(idx)<=b` occur in the middle of the array, something like `A = 1e9:-1:1; b = 1e9/2;`. Second, it would also be interesting to see how the timing changes for the two approaches as the size of the array `A` increases. How large does `A` have to be for the overhead of looping to become less than the time spent unnecessarily processing the entire array?

Comment: To your first point: I agree, I did run this test outputting `idx` several times to ensure it wasn't too early, results seem representative but no hard data on that (yet). To your second point: see my note about wanting to make a plot, the looping method was too quick to time reliably so little point trying to compare on smaller arrays...

Comment: Using random values in `A` in the range `[0,1)` and `b = 0.01` you're going to average hitting a value where `A(idx) <= b` at around `idx == 100`. That's probably why you're finishing so quickly with the looped version. You're only hitting 0.00001% of the array on average.

Comment: I used different values of `b` in my tests, but have taken your suggestion on board and done a more thorough investigation, please see the edit.

Comment: Great! That looks like it gives a better comparison.